# Python - Appending data to an existing file or reading file

Tags: python, readfile

Please write a program which works as a simply diary. The diary entries should be saved in the file diary.txt. When the program is executed, it should first read any entries already in the file.

The expected output can be seen in the screenshots below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lJVg.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnWle.png)
Here's my code:

```
with open("diary.txt") as my_file:
    entries = my_file.read()
while True:
    operation = input("1 - add an entry, 2 - read entries, 0 - quit\nFunction:")
    if operation == "1":
        content = input("Diary entry: ")
        with open("diary.txt","a") as diary:
            diary.write(f"{content}\n")
        print("Diary saved\n")
    elif operation == "2":
        print("Entries: ")
        with open("diary.txt") as diary:
            for row in diary:
                print(row)
    elif operation == "0":
        print('Bye now!'+"\n")
        break
```

However, when I submitted it to TMC, it fails one trial, and says like this:
DiaryTest: test_1_exit_only
Your program should output two lines with input
0
Now it outputs
Bye now!

Anyone could pls help me check why I got a result like this?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when finishing the exercise. I went through the `test_diary.py` file for how the test cases were getting executed and figured this out.
For your last `elif` condition where it asks the user to quit by pressing <kbd>0</kbd>, instead of your `print` statement, you need to write

```py
print('Bye now!'+'\nBye now!')
```

The `assert` statement that caused the error goes like this

```py
self.assertTrue(
    len(output.split("\n")) == 2, 
    f"Your program should output two lines with input\n{input_value}\nNow it outputs\n{output}"
)
```

I believe it's an error on their part since the length of the output would be 1 but, since for other test cases they are not checking for the quit statement, 'Bye now!', it only matters for the first case where its checking twice.
So, making the change should grant you the exercise point.

Comment: Hi! 
Thank you for your reply! I have sent an email to the teacher of the course regarding this problem. It is suggested that we can change the very beginning part like this: 
instead of 
input(instructions + "\n" + "Function: "
but
print(instructions)
input("Function: ")

Answer (score 0):

To pass the test case you can apply the solution from Kunjan Rana above or just modify your code so that
the function options are printed out separate to the input like below. It counts that print statement below as line 1 and the print statement for Bye now! as line 2.

```
print("1 - add an entry, 2 - read entries, 0 - quit")
function = input("Function: ")
```